# Succinct way to handle Form Data on Django using the save() method

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In a Bookstore application, I have a form to add a `Book` written by an `Author` and a `Shelf` which belongs to a `Bookstore`. A book needs to be associated to a Shelf.

```
class AddBookForm(forms.Form):

    def save(self, request):
        #Let's say I put an excrutiating number of fields...say 13.
        book_name = self.cleaned_data.get('book_name', None)
        book_author_pk = self.cleaned_data.get('book_author_pk', None)
        book_genre = self.cleaned_data.get('genre', None)
        book_price = self.cleaned_data.get('price', None)
        book_summary = self.cleaned_data.get('book_summary', None)
        bookshop_location = self.cleaned_data.get('bookshop_location', None)
        bookshop_shelf_number = self.cleaned_data.get('bookshop_shelf_number', None)
        stock = self.cleaned_data.get('stock', None)
        promotional_price = self.cleaned_data.get('promotional_price', None)

        author_object = Author.objects.get(pk=book_author_pk)

        book = Book(
            name = book_name,
            author = author_object,
            genre = genre,
            summary = book_summary
        )
        book.save(force_insert=True)

        shelf = Shelf(
            bookshop_location = bookshop_location,
            shelf_number = bookshop_shelf_number,
            stock = stock,
            promotional_price = promotional_price
        )
        shelf.save(force_insert=True, force_update=False)
```

My question is: Is there actually a more succinct way to write this? I'm pretty sure that there is but I'm missing it somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean a `ModelForm`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: What if the form will populate more than 1 model? I think that should be a more appropriate question. Yes, I know how to use ModelForms.

Comment: Please try to create an [mcve]. Generally, don't have a form do more than one model - let the view handle that

Comment: If you have more than one model to process, you should use two modelforms, it's the same concept.

Comment: updated the question. yes in the previous example the modelform works.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
class AddFruitForm(forms.Form):

    def save(self, request):       
        # list all your fields here
        fields_expected = ['fruit_name', 'fruit_color', ...]

        # this should give you the dict with all the fields equal to "None" 
        fields = dict.fromkeys(fields_expected)     

        # this relace the None value with the good data from cleaned_data
        fields.update(self.cleaned_data)

        # assign all the in the dict to the model, key=value
        fruit = Fruit(**fields)
        fruit.save(force_insert=True, force_update=False)
```

However if your model can accept None for those value you shouldn't have to provide to the model explicitly as above, you can do this instead and let the model to handle the default value.

```
class AddFruitForm(forms.Form):

    def save(self, request):       
        fields = self.cleaned_data
        fields['my_custom_field'] = 'some data not from the field'

        fruit = Fruit(**fields)
        fruit.save(force_insert=True, force_update=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is associated with models, it's best to use `ModelForm`. You could have as many form as you want in the front end and submit them altogether. The code is really straight forward:

```
# models.py
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = Book

class Shelf(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = Shelf

# views.py
def addbook(request):
    book_form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
    shelf_form = SelfForm(request.POST or None)
    if book_form.is_valid() and shelf_form.is_valid():
        book = book_form.save()
        shelf = shelf_form.save()
        return redirect('some-list-view')

    return render(request, 
                  'addbook.html', 
                  {'book_form': book_form, 'shelf_form': shelf_form})

# addbook.html
<form action="/addbook/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ book_form }}
    {{ shelf_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: hmm, I use CBV so this won't be that useful for use. Also, I use Django Crispy Forms package so I would like to be able to control the look and field of the form appropriately.

Comment: You could still use CBV to get this done, but not `CreateView`, maybe just inherit from `View` instead, but it's the same concept. I simplified the front end, but there's nothing prevent you from customizing the front end. I'm just giving you suggestions, not a copy-paste solution.